From String to JSON back to String properties order
I cannot find how JSON order object properties.
I thought it was alphabetical, but it seems it isn't.
I've tried to find how JSON ordering object properties but I can't find it.

Could you please explain one of the JSON ordering benefits ?

There must be some rule, but I just don't understand that rule.
Obviously because of that rule engine changes order.
